# What key is the hardest to turn?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

A simple one-liner:

> What key is the hardest to turn?

What is the answer?

Comment: This question sounds like very open ended and subject to interpretation. For example words that end in "key" like hockey or smokey (there are dozens) can be listed as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A

> musical key, because it's a sound - a type of vibration - and thus can't be "turned" in a lock.

Comment: N pelcgbtencuvp xrl zvtug nyfb or na rdhnyyl inyvq nafjre gb guvf, sbe fvzvyne ernfbaf...